# How to add an attachment to a mail message using PHP?

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a form, which allows users to submit a support request.  The form also allows users to send an attachment (jpeg/pdf etc..)

Once the form has been submitted, it sends an email of confirmation back to the user outlining their request, but also sends another to basecamp (project management software) where it logs this request.

The email for basecamp should be in 2 parts; content goes to one email, attachments to another.

Something like (just an basic example):

```
$email_A = "project1@live.com";
$subject_A = "Todo:";
$message_A = "* Milk
              * Bread";

$email_B = "project-image@live.com";
$subject_B = "Files";
$message_B = "";

mail($email_A, $subject_A, $message_A);
mail($email_B, $subject_B, $message_B);
```

How would I attach the file that the user has uploaded in the form to the above message ($message_B)so that it sends it in an email to basecamp? It says in basecamp that to attach the files via email all you need to do is put the subject as "Files" and insert the attachment in the body of the email?

Comment: To send an attachment with mail() is more difficult than you think. Try using an email class such as PHPMailer which makes it as easy as calling a method.

Answer (score 1):

If you so want it...

```
$boundary = md5(uniqid(rand()));
$headers = "From: webmaster@site.com\r\n"
    ."Mime: 1.0\r\n"
    ."Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=\"".$boundary."\"\r\n";

$body = "--".$boundary."\r\n"
    ."Content-Type: text/html;charset=\"UTF8\"\r\n"
    ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"
    .chunk_split(base64_encode($text))."\r\n\r\n"
    // second part of mail - attachment
    ."--".$boundary."\r\n"
    ."Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"
    ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
    ."Content-Description: imageXXX.jpg\r\n"
    ."Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"imageXXX.jpg\"\r\n"
    .chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/34600000/Beautiful-Red-Roses-roses-34610966-1920-1080.jpg')))."\r\n\r\n"
    ."--".$boundary."--\r\n";

mail($to, $subj, $body, $headers);
```

I think you will get my point.